# How can we return simple text from a django function based view

Tags: django, django-views

I started django about 2 days back , I have to write an api which should return text json like

```
"{"key":"value"}"
```

My view.py is like this

```
def test(request):
if request.method=="GET":
    return "{"key":"value"}"
```

but i am getting an error , DJango is not returning a http response object 
when i use the function render to print text like

```
def test(request):
if request.method=="GET":
    render(request,"{"key":"value"}")
```

i am getting "TemplateDoesNotExist" error .

Answer (score 1):

Every django view must return a http response, You appear to be trying to return json, so you should use a [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({"key":"value"})
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . this saved a lot of time !!

Comment: @TejaReddy - No worries... Please next time, you should try to look on google for the error message as most of them have plenty of duplicates. If that doesn't help then you should include your research in your question. The only reason I answered this is because this answer wasn't in the first 3 (similar) pages I clicked on